# iSCSI connection from Ubuntu server timeouts when booting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iscsi

we set up an Ubuntu server (22.04.3 LTS) to use as a Veeam Repository. We want to connect a LUN on a NetApp storage via iSCSI.
The setup itself went without a problem till the server had to be rebootet.
After the reboot the server ended up at the emergency prompt, logging in and checking the system nothing unusual was to be found, so I completed the boot and all was good.
When I rebooted to find the problem the messages showed that there was a problem mounting the iSCSI LUN and when again we ended at the emergency prompt, this time I told it to complete booting  (Control+D) a minute or two later and again, everthing was fine.
Further attempts did not give any further information, so I went to check the logs. This are the relevant parts I found:

It tries to mount the filesystem early in the boot which of course fails

```
Jan 29 12:37:42 hwlxve01 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5e252ca3\x2d9f19\x2d4a9c\x2d946d\x2d4cd4e02d29ff.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5e252ca3\x2d9f19\x2d4a9c\x2d946d\x2d4cd4e02d29ff.device/start timed out.
Jan 29 12:37:42 hwlxve01 systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/5e252ca3-9f19-4a9c-946d-4cd4e02d29ff.
Jan 29 12:37:42 hwlxve01 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /mnt/veeam-hr01.
Jan 29 12:37:42 hwlxve01 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
Jan 29 12:37:42 hwlxve01 systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Job local-fs.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jan 29 12:37:42 hwlxve01 systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
Jan 29 12:37:42 hwlxve01 systemd[1]: mnt-veeam\x2dhr01.mount: Job mnt-veeam\x2dhr01.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jan 29 12:37:42 hwlxve01 systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5e252ca3\x2d9f19\x2d4a9c\x2d946d\x2d4cd4e02d29ff.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5e252ca3\x2d9f19\x2d4a9c\x2d946d\x2d4cd4e02d29ff.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
```

a bit later network is coming up, for example

`Jan 29 12:37:44 hwlxve01 kernel: ixgbe 0000:03:00.1 enp3s0f1: NIC Link is Up 10 Gbps, Flow Control: RX/TX`

then iSCSI starts logging in

`Jan 29 12:38:01 hwlxve01 systemd[1]: Starting Login to default iSCSI targets...`

and 90 second later runs into a timeout

```
Jan 29 12:39:31 hwlxve01 systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/5e252ca3-9f19-4a9c-946d-4cd4e02d29ff.
Jan 29 12:39:31 hwlxve01 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /mnt/veeam-hr01.
```

this error comes up a few times:

```
Jan 29 12:39:32 hwlxve01 iscsiadm[986]: iscsiadm: Could not login to [iface: iscsi02, target: iqn.1992-08.com.netapp:sn.c45dccd4641511ee880bd039eaaae634:vs.7, portal: 192.168.114.3,3260].
Jan 29 12:39:32 hwlxve01 iscsiadm[986]: iscsiadm: initiator reported error (20 - could not connect to iscsid)
```

and hurray, it goes to Emergency Shell

```
Jan 29 12:42:34 hwlxve01 systemd[1]: Started Emergency Shell.
Jan 29 12:42:34 hwlxve01 systemd[1]: Reached target Emergency Mode.
```

and a few seconds later it can successfully connect on all paths

```
Jan 29 12:42:35 hwlxve01 systemd[1]: Started iSCSI initiator daemon (iscsid).
Jan 29 12:42:35 hwlxve01 kernel: Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
Jan 29 12:42:35 hwlxve01 kernel: iscsi: registered transport (tcp)
Jan 29 12:42:35 hwlxve01 kernel: scsi host11: iSCSI Initiator over TCP/IP
Jan 29 12:42:35 hwlxve01 kernel: scsi host12: iSCSI Initiator over TCP/IP
Jan 29 12:42:35 hwlxve01 kernel: scsi 11:0:0:0: Direct-Access     NETAPP   LUN C-Mode       9131 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
Jan 29 12:42:35 hwlxve01 kernel: scsi 11:0:0:0: alua: supports implicit TPGS
Jan 29 12:42:35 hwlxve01 kernel: scsi 11:0:0:0: alua: device naa.600a098038314c6f445d565238477871 port group 3e9 rel port 6
Jan 29 12:42:35 hwlxve01 kernel: sd 11:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
```

and multipath does its job

```
Jan 29 12:42:36 hwlxve01 multipathd[659]: mpatha: reload [0 176093659136 multipath 3 pg_init_retries 50 queue_if_no_path 1 alua 2 1 service-time 0 1 1 8:16 1 service-time 0 2 1 8:48 1 8:32 1]
```

OK, I know iSCSI logins can take time, but this long seems weird.
Also, why do I get the iSCSI daemon connection error?

What can I do?

If further logs are needed let me know.

I built a few similar setups and nowhere am I running into a similar problem.